# React JS Bundle Load Issue -- SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am getting this strange issue in the browser "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression..."

Any pointers?

I have read other similar posts suggesting to include utf-8 in the header or src both of which I have done as shown in the code below.

I have a react project, and it's producing bundle.js with webpack and included as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is the entire package.json I am using:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "start": "webpack serve"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.1"
  }
}
```

And the error in chrome console is:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /([Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(<[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(\s*,\s*[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*)*>)?\s+)+[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s*\(/: Range out of order in character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at n (core.js:836)
    at t (core.js:1136)
    at core.js:1151
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t (core.js:1151)
    at H (core.js:1171)
    at m (core.js:1975)
    at Object.p [as highlight] (core.js:1626)
    at Object.o [as highlight] (react-dom.production.min.js:79)
ss @ react-dom.production.min.js:268
bootstrap:22 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /([Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(<[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(\s*,\s*[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*)*>)?\s+)+[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s*\(/: Range out of order in character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at n (core.js:836)
    at t (core.js:1136)
    at core.js:1151
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t (core.js:1151)
    at H (core.js:1171)
    at m (core.js:1975)
    at Object.p [as highlight] (core.js:1626)
    at Object.o [as highlight] (react-dom.production.min.js:79)
```